# css animation makes the image-hyperlink no longer clickable

Tags: html, css

I have an image with a hyperlink, which simplified looks like:

```
<div class="button-div">
  <a href="xxx"><img src="xxx"></a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to create an animation effect for the image using css, with the help of [this tutorial](https://www.b3multimedia.ie/custom-divi-blurbs-part-1/) (although written for the divi theme, which I don't use). Part of the styling to be added is:

```
.button-div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  /* This is your ripple color & size */
  border: #00cc69 solid 6px;
  /* Uncomment the line below if it's a circle*/
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

Although this successfully creates the animation effect, the image is no longer clickable. Or to be more precise: only the transparant corners of the circle-image are still clickable. But if I remove the line `content: ''` the image is correctly clickable but the animation effect is gone.

How can I make both the animation and hyperlink work together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `::before` pseudo-element is stacked on top of the `<a>` element in your `.button-div`, and it is therefore capturing all click events instead. You can use [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on the pseudo-element to ensure click events passes through it and down to the `<a>` element underneath.

```
.button-div:before {
  /* Ensures pseudo element does not receive pointer events */
  pointer-events: none;

  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: #00cc69 solid 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
```